# Old frozen ground lamb - safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, lamb, ground

I found some old frozen ground lamb in the back of the freezer.  It is vacuum sealed, and was placed in the freezer after a couple days of being fresh.

It has been in the freezer for a little over 4 years.

Is it safe to eat?

Answer (score 2):

If it has remained frozen, it is safe.  However, even vacuum packed, its flavor has probably degraded. It simply might taste very good.